# как для этой строки задать условие

Tags: yii2

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

            $this->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

как для этой строки задать условие

```
$this->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
```

insert нужно если инстер, то возвращать строку текущего пользователя

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($insert) {$this->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($insert) {
        $this->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    }
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```